# Inserting multiple rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some help on inserting lines in two sheets in excel.

I have the following code which works

```
Sub Button1_Click()
r0w = Selection.Row
c0l = Selection.Column
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r0w, c0l).EntireRow.Insert
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r0w, c0l).EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

however there are a few things I need to change and I am not sure how to proceed.

1. sheet 1 just contains names, my aim hopefully is to insert a row in sheet 1 and then a row is also added to sheet 2. My problem is that the formatting in sheet 2 is different to sheet 1.
   so for example, sheet 1 will have a different name in row 5  say Dave, than sheet 2.
   is there a way for the line in sheet 2 to be added below Dave in sheet 2 so that the names continue in alphabetical order in both sheet 1 and 2.
2. I would like the Code to Run when the user enters a Capital I anywhere in column A.

any help would be very much appreciated

Thanks
Col

Comment: You might start by researching the [Worksheet.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Comment: Please re-consider your work flow. If you insert a row in Sheet2 every time you enter "i" in Sheet1 you will spend the rest of your days deleting useless rows in Sheet2. You must complete the entire row in Sheet1, then press a button to make a corresponding entry in Sheet2. I sometimes have a dedicated column in which I place a checkmark when the copy has been made and placing that mark actually triggers the copying. Yes, the copy can be made in any location or you can sort the sheet after adding it at the bottom.

Comment: Hi I only want the to insert a Capital "I" in Column A and then have the code execute.